# Implementing CallBacks in MainActivity: Expecting Member Declaration Error

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, callback

I'm Trying to implement callbacks on Main Activity, therefore I can switch the fragments based on user behavior. I implemented it above onCreate `CrimeListFragment.Callbacks`  but i got an error (Expecting Member Declaration)

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    /*
    Implementing callbacks inside the hosting activity to change the fragment once needed.
     */
    CrimeListFragment.Callbacks {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


            /*
      to add a fragment into activity in code, we call FragmentManager.
      we instantiate the fragment with the fragment manager. and set the condition to show it
      in case it is null, call fragment manager to start transaction and add the fragment container
      as the view and its code file CrimeFragment() in action, then commit them to OS.

      transactions are used to add, remove, attach, detach or replace a fragment
       */
            val currentFragment = //<--  When we need to retrieve the CrimeFragment from
                // the fragment manager you asked for it by container view ID
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)

            if (currentFragment == null) {
                val fragment = CrimeListFragment.newInstance()
                supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit()
            }

        }


        override fun onCrimeSelected(crimeid: UUID) {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, CrimeFragment())
                .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the reserved word `class`

```
class CrimeListFragment.Callbacks {...
```

That is not a callback implementation, that is an inner class declaration.

Also, you are writing methods from a fragment there, but you are not extending fragment

```
class CrimeListFragment.Callbacks : Fragment {
```

If you already have `CrimeListFragment.Callbacks` **interface** defined inside `CrimeListFragment`, then what you want to do is:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CrimeListFragment.Callbacks {
```

And that will force you to implement the methods defined in the `interface` `CrimeListFragment.Callbacks` in your activity.